# CMSMS FormBuilder submit call custom function

Tags: forms, content-management-system, builder, formbuilder, cmsmadesimple

I am using CMS Made Simple for my website.

I have some custom PHP code which I would like to call when a users clicks submit on my Form Builder form.

I know my code is now working correctly, but I cannot seem to find where in the FormBuilder code that I can call the function.

I have had a look through the code in the modules directory but I cannot seem to find where I need to put the code.

Preferably I would like to only use this code on certain forms, but if I have to implement for all forms then so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormBuilder has a field to call UDTs.  In the Fast field adder dropdown choose *Call A User Defined Tag With the Form Results"  You may have to use Advanced mode

There is also the UDT integration tab.